# How do you write to a person and group column with JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

How can I write data to a list column of type "Person and Group" using JavaScript or jQuery? I can find examples for doing it with C# and REST. Not sure if there's a more modern way with Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Do you want to update the "Person or Group" column using MS Graph API with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To save the value in the "Person and Group" field, you have to pass the user ID. You can follow answer shared in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271440/the-proper-way-to-write-a-sharepoint-user-to-a-user-field-in-a-sharepoint-list

also you can follow https://gist.github.com/rheid/18635032d8371c7825b3320eae57071f for correct format to use to save data for all type of SharePoint fields using javascript